# MacOS Mojave terminal's font does not change. It shows every user installed font as Helvetica

Tags: macos, fonts, terminal, macos-mojave, powerline

I have a Macbook Pro 15" 2018 with MacOS Mojave.

I use `vim` and `tmux` and I had my terminal font set to one of powerline fonts. Everything was working fine but when I tried to change the font today out of sudden, it shows every powerline and user fonts as "Helvetica".

I removed the fonts and installed them again but it didn't help. Also I rebooted the Macbook but it didn't change anything.

I'd appreciate it if anyone has any suggestions.

***Update***

I noticed that if I change the default profile theme the fonts would work. But the Basic theme still renders all other fonts with Helvetica.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/). It is not about programming.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you might have a corrupt font cache. The easiest way to clear this is by doing a Safe Boot, (hold down SHIFT at power up); and then restart normally.

Utilities like Onyx often provide a GUI control for clearing the font cache (among others). You can also do it with a terminal command:

```
sudo atsutil databases -remove
```

Then restart. Note that this may reset any font disabling you've done in FontBook.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @benwiggy. I tried this but it still shows every non-system fonts as Helvetica.

Comment: I noticed that if I change the default profile theme the fonts would work. But the Basic theme still renders all other fonts with Helvetica. So is there a way to delete the cache for a specific theme of the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other answer, I had a corrupt font cache. I was able to restore default profile by going to `Terminal > Preferences > Profile`. On the bottom of the theme column on the left click the gear icon and select *"Restore Default Profiles"*

This fixed the issue.

Comment: In addition, I had to quit terminal completely and restart to get things reflected as and when you reconfigure the options
(I'm on Monterey, btw)